# Foreign key relationships with the same table for two different foreign key columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Lets say I have a **user** and **appointment** table.

> **users** - id, name, email, type(doctor/patient)
>
> **appointment**- id, doctor_user_id, patient_user_id

My user table data-

[image]

And my appointment table data-

[image]

I could make two **belongs to** **relationships** from **appointment** with **user** table.

As you can see my **appointment** table, I want to store only **user** that type is **doctor** to **doctor_user_id** and **patient** to **patient_user_id**. But in this case i can add any user id to **doctor_user_id** field either it is **doctor or patient** but i want to add only user id as doctor_user_id only if its type is doctor.

I know how to achieve this with **two different** table but I was wondering is there any way to achieve this with **single user** table, Thanks.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: ok, i am updating

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can achieve this by creating one **user** table only.

Create 2 foreign key for the "doctor_user_id" and "patient_user_id" of **appointment** table which references to User table.

Comment: but this doesn't ensure that doctor_user_id is of type doctor

Comment: In SQL server, we can manage this by the "Check Constraint", but MySQL didn't. You can achieve the same by trigger http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint/... So before inserting/updating data ensure that inserted record for "doctor_user_id" is type of the doctor only.

Comment: Either you can manage the same from the PHP code before insert/update

Answer (score 3):

You can use two `belongsToMany()` relationships and use the table as I pivot:

```
public function doctors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'appointment', 'patient_user_id', 'doctor_user_id');
}

public function patients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'appointment', 'doctor_user_id', 'patient_user_id');
}
```

If you'll use the `appointment` table a lot, you can also add two `hasMany()` relationships to the `Appointment` model and two `belongsTo()` relationships to the `User` model. So, you could use `belongsToMany()`, `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` relationships simultaneously for in this case.

Comment: how can i ensure that doctor_user_id is of type doctor??

Comment: If there was a doctor table, than i can easily conclude that its type is doctor, but how can i ensure through a enum field as here it is the type column

Comment: @Sohel0415 you'll do that when you'll attach doctors to patients with `attach()` or `sync`. When you're getting the data, just use `doctors` or `patients` relationship to get the type of users you want. It's just a simple many-to-many relationship, so use it like any other many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @Sohel0415 what exactly do you mean? You'll have FKs and pivot table (`appointment`) for that.

Comment: i can ensure that doctor_user_id is present on user table through FKs but can't ensure its type

Comment: @Sohel0415 you can if you use the relationships. When you'll use `doctors()` with methods like `with()` and `load()`, you'll get doctors only. To filter by user type, just use this relationship with `whereHas()` etc.